# How to use a named union or structure as anonymous

Tags: c++

I have some code where I define a union as:

```
  union myP{    
    ptr addr;
    hGeneric* hGenericP;
  };
```

I need to use the above union inside a structure but as an unnamed union as if I had written:

```
  struct XXXX{
    union{
      ptr addr;
      hGeneric* hGenericP;
    };
    union{
      Token nextFree;
      ....
    };
  };
```

Actually I write the field lines in another file and I include them in both

```
union myP{  
    #include "fieldsOf_myP"
  };
```

I need to use the above union inside a structure but as an unnamed union as if I had written:

```
  struct XXXX{
    union{
      #include "fieldsOf_myP"
    };
    union{
      Token nextFree;
      ....
    };
  };
```

That way my IDE ( codeLite ) doesn't sees those fields and doesn't shows them during code writting. Is there a way to just write the union name and use it as unnamed ?

Does the answer bellow using inheritance work with my exact code bellow ?

```
union headP{
            ptr addr;
            hGeneric* hGenericP;
            hVarBase<agu>* hVarP;
            hAggregateBase<Word>* hAggregateP;
            void(*executeFunction)();
};


union vect{
    struct{
        union{
            ptr addr;
            hGeneric* hGenericP;
            hFixBase<agu>*  hFixP;
            hVarBase<agu>* hVarP;
            hAggregateBase<Word>* hAggregateP;
            void(*executeFunction)();
        };

        union{
            Token nextFree;
            struct{
                suWord Class;
                suWord executionLevel:(sWordBits-shortClassBits);
                uint8_t shortClass:shortClassBits;
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: About codelite, have you activated clang completion ?

Comment: The IDE shows other members but doesn't shows those that are included via #include "fieldsOf_myP" . I looked for the clang completion but I didn't find where that option is. I use g++ ( and some times clang).

Comment: `struct bob{ union{int a; int b;};}; class foo { struct:bob{}; };` ?  (note the `:`) -- may require extension, may not work.

Comment: @Yakk: `struct foo : bob{};` seems simpler and doesn't require any extension...

Comment: Seems good but look in the question my exact code that uses unions, and inheritance doesn't seem to adapt.

Comment: @jarod42 at least one compiler treats anonymous `struct`s like anonymous `union`s in that it folds their members into the enclosing `class`.  The `struct:bob` is not the extension I was talking about.  In other research, [`-fms-extensions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) might also solve your problem.